# email map validation in firestore

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I know that email validation is quite a difficult thing to do. I have already written a regex that checks for a valid email adress. The problem is writing the security rule, seeing as I am dealing with a map in cloud firestore. The map looks like this:

```
email{
    work: ""
    personal: ""
}
```

The problem is the fact that I cannot guarantee that a specific value will match the regex. Users should be able to  have only a personal email, only a work email or both a personal and work email. All of the situations should result in validated email adresses in firestore.

I currently have the following code, but I can't figure out how to deal with maps like this:

```
match /organisations/{orgID}/people/{userID} {
    allow create: if(request.resource.data.email.matches(^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}[.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}$) == true);
}
```

Is this doable with just one security rule? If yes, how? If no, how do I manage this another way? I'd rather use security rules over writing a cloud function for this if possible.

I currently have something like this, but I get an error because firebase doesn't seem to recognize the | (OR) operator. Is there any alternative for doing this? I'm tring to test if the email is either valid or null.

```
match /organisations/{orgID}/people/{userID}{
    allow create: if(
        request.resource.data.email.work.matches(^[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,}[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,}[.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,}$|"") 
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two distinct problems here.  They are not directly related to each other.  I will try to address them separately.

> The problem is writing the security rule, seeing as I am dealing with a map in cloud firestore.

If you want to use the value of a nested field within map field, you can simply use dot notation to get to it:

```
request.resource.data.email.work
request.resource.data.email.personal
```

> The problem is the fact that I cannot guarantee that a specific value will match the regex. Users should be able to have only a personal email, only a work email or both a personal and work email.

You will need to write logic to check each map field separately.  You can't check all fields of the map at the same time.

Comment: So that would mean that I should write a security rule for each key in a map? If so, how could I have it so it allows if the data either matches the regex or is null?

Comment: Something like this? ^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}[@]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}[.]{1}[A-Za-z0-9.]{3,}$|null

Comment: I'm not in a good position to debug your regex.  But you will have to check each field separately.

Comment: I have tested the regex in a regex validator and it gives the results I wanted and expected. However, it gives an errow when copying the regex into the firestore security rules, as firestore doesn't recognize the OR operator. Does anyone know an alternative to this, or perhaps a fix?